# mean and sd of the day in R with xts

Tags: r, xts, zoo, mean, standard-deviation

again I do have my df in xts and don't have names! (as far as I know there is no name anymore when setting as.POSIXct()):

```
    "2012-04-09 05:00:00",2
    "2012-04-09 09:00:00",4
    "2012-04-09 12:00:00",5
    "2012-04-09 22:00:00",0
    "2012-04-10 04:00:00",0
    "2012-04-10 06:00:00",3
    "2012-04-10 08:00:00",0
    "2012-04-10 12:00:00",1
```

I wanna calculate the mean and sd of the day - not of the whole df.

```
df2<-period.apply(df, endpoints(df, "hours", 24), mean)
```

works but I am getting not the mean of one day - and how to deal with the standard deviation?
Thanks

Comment: If you want "days", you can just do that instead of 24 "hours".  `period.apply(df, endpoints(df, "days"), mean)`.  Standard deviation is the same: `period.apply(df, endpoints(df, "days"), sd)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `apply.daily` do what you want?

```
> apply.daily(df, mean)
                    [,1]
2012-04-09 22:00:00 2.75
2012-04-10 12:00:00 1.00
> apply.daily(df, sd)
                        [,1]
2012-04-09 22:00:00 2.217356
2012-04-10 12:00:00 1.414214
```

Answer (score 1):

```
by(value,as.Date(df$timestamp),mean)
by(value,as.Date(df$timestamp),sd)
```